# Material-UI useMediaQuery not initially recognising correct breakpoint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

While using the MUI `useMediaQuery` hook, I noticed my react app being buggy and throwing errors because the hook initially does not recognise the correct breakpoint, then the page quickly re-renders with the correct value.

Example:

```
const mobile = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.only('mobile'));
console.log(mobile)
```

Console:

```
false
true
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of `useMediaQuery` hook. It's explained in the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/components/use-media-query/#api):

> To perform the server-side hydration, the hook needs to render twice. A first time with false, the value of the server, and a second time with the resolved value. This double pass rendering cycle comes with a drawback. It's slower. You can set this option to true if you are doing client-side only rendering.

So to get the correct value on the first page render the `noSsr` option in the `useMediaQuery` hook needs to be `true`.

There are two options:

**1) Per component:**

```
const mobile = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.only('mobile'), {noSsr: true});
```

**2) Globally in the `theme` object:**

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiUseMediaQuery: {
      defaultProps: {
          noSsr: true,
      },
    },
  }
```

Obviously, this will only work *without* server-side rendering.

The original answer below works in Material-UI v4, but the `Hidden` component has been [deprecated in v5](https://mui.com/components/hidden/#main-content).

**Original answer:**

I realised that by removing the media query and replacing it with the Material-UI `<Hidden />` component it works how I want it to.

```
export const ResponsiveMenuItem = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { children, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <>
      <Hidden smUp>
        <option ref={ref} {...other}>
          {children}
        </option>
      </Hidden>
      <Hidden only="xs">
        <MenuItem ref={ref} {...other}>
          {children}
        </MenuItem>
      </Hidden>
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('xs'), {noSsr: true}); this is not working. returning false in the first render and only then returning correct value

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and went from

```
const breakpointDownLg = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("lg"));
{breakpointDownLg ? <Navigation /> : <DesktopNavigation /> }
```

to

```
<Box sx={{ display: { lg: "none" } }} >
 <Navigation />
</Box>
<Box sx={{ display: {xs: "none", lg: "block" } }}>
 <DesktopNavigation />
</Box>
```

This seem to work
https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/v5-component-changes/#hidden